# How to add ROS_LİB in Arduino Libraries

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-lib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I want to add ros_lib in arduino libraries . Because ı have to run a arduino code and it includes ros.h . Please help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270901/how-to-add-ros_li%CC%87b-in-arduino-libraries/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2017-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can follow along with this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup. Make sure to install your sketch into the `<sketchbook>/libraries` folder using

```
ros rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py <sketchbook>/libraries/
```

where `<sketchbook>` is the path to your sketchbook.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-09-14**:
I did it @jayess but ı got such an error : `

make_libraries.py generates the Arduino rosserial library files.  It
requires the location of your Arduino sketchbook/libraries folder.

rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py <output_path>

`

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-09-14**:
The problem is solved .  That would be very helpful . I can not thank you enough Mr. @jayess

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-14**:
@Mekateng: No problem, glad to help. Please mark this answer as correct.